# Default route for root path using asp.net attribute routing

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-routing, self-hosting, visual-studio-2013, owin

I'm using attribute routing from ASP.NET 5 RC, included in the Visual Studio 2013 RC release.

I'd like for the root path, `/`, to lead to the canonical `/Home/Index` path, but I can't find a way to do this with just attribute routes. Is it possible, and if not, how would I do it if I'm also using OWIN SelfHost? In other words, I'm setting up my own `HttpConfiguration` class manually in the `WebApp.Start<T>` method (where `T` has a `Configure(IAppBuilder)` method invoked at startup) and not going through the `RouteTable.Routes` object. Or should I be going through the `RouteTable.Routes` object? I haven't had much luck with that when I tried it...

EDIT: Here's what I've tried so far:

```
// normal Web API attribute routes
config.MapHttpAttributeRoutes();

config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
   name: "DefaultWeb",
   routeTemplate: "{controller}/{action}",
   defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index" }
);
```

The second try below looks a little dubious, since it's not clear how my `HttpConfiguration` object is related to the static `RouteTable.Routes` object:

```
// normal Web API attribute routes
config.MapHttpAttributeRoutes();

RouteTable.Routes.MapRoute(
   name: "DefaultWeb",
   url: "{controller}/{action}",
   defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index" }
);
```

Answer (score 29):

You can set the default route for the app like this:

```
    [Route("~/", Name = "default")]
    public ActionResult Index() {
        return View();
    }
```

Comment: I got "The current request is ambiguous between the following action methods: ..." when trying this. I added [RoutePrefix( "home" )] to my controller definition and changed [Route] to [Route( "index" )] to remove the ambiguity. Both / (default) and /home/index now work.

Comment: I also got the ambiguous error, and the ambiguity was pointing both to the same controller. I removed the "[Route]" shown above and now it works.

Answer (score 1):

For anyone who is using .NET Core 1.x, you'll need to do this as well as use Jay's answer above.

In your Startup.cs file, add this to your `Configure` method.

`app.UseMvcWithDefaultRoute();`

Then, any controller action you want as the default, put the attribute `[Route("", Name = "default")]`